# Busboy not working in Google Cloud Function (using Postman)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, multipartform-data, busboy

I am attempting to send an image to my google cloud function to store in my google storage bucket. I am using Postman to test my function, but I am getting no where.

This is the code I am using for the cloud function.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const Busboy = require('busboy');

const storage = new Storage();

functions.http('hello', (req, res) => {
    const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      console.log('Received file:', filename);
      console.log('File size:', file.length, 'bytes');
      console.log('MIME type:', mimetype);
    });

  busboy.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error occurred during file upload:', err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });

   busboy.on('finish', () => {
    res.send(filename);
    res.end();
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);

});
```

Node version: 20
Busboy version: 1.6

EDIT: I have confirmed that the req.body is being sent correctly.

Comment: wrap all of your code in a function that looks like this for example.  exports.uploadFile = async (req, res) => {....all your code...} then do this:  npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=uploadFile to run locally

Comment: @smoore4 the request is now exceeding time limit. I am only uploading a pdf file less than a mb.